# Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1, but version 9.0.2 is needed for the google-services plugin

Tags: android, google-play-services

The title is the error I'm getting trying to compile my Android app.
This looks like a recurring problem, but none of the answers for the questions of the same kind helped me.

I've got this in my project's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

And this in my app's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.21'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.21'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When I try replacing com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1 with com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.0.2, then I get this compile error:

```
Error:(38, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.0.2
```

Any idea?

Comment: did u try to refresh dependencies ```gradle build --refresh-dependencies``` ...or build-->clean project

Comment: in your .idea, libraries folder what does your version say??

Comment: I see this file among others: play_services_places_9_2_1.xml.

Comment: This is what i tried.. i deleted that xml and synced my gradle file. and it was recreated... can u give that a shot

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it was a version discrepancy between play-services-places and firebase, see my answer. Thanks

Comment: I thought you wanted to downgrade from 9 2 1 to 9 0 2.. anyways cheers!!! happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the problem was coming from this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
```

I changed it to this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
```

And now it works in unison with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1'
```