# Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1, but version 9.0.0 is needed and Duplicate zza.class errors

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I have a react-native project and I'm trying to setup google signin on it. To that I need to setup the react-native-google-signin plugin which asks me to add the following to the build.gradle file :

```
compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
}

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
```

When I do this, I get a build error like this :

```
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
:app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.62 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment.
Go to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
and check the Android tab for setup instructions.
```

When I make the play-services-auth 9.0.0, it gives me this error :

```
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zza.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.107 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment.
Go to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
and check the Android tab for setup instructions.
```

My build.gradle dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile(project(':react-native-firebase-analytics')){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile project(':react-native-share')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile project(':react-native-uuid-generator')
    compile project(':react-native-udp')
    compile project(':react-native-tcp')
    compile project(':react-native-code-push')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any idea what's happening? I tried many fixes suggested on other threads but none helped. I will get these two errors all the time. Please help!

Full error logs are here : https://gist.github.com/THPubs/1ca6405f62671c698c4aee0c73c8324e

Comment: Are there any JAR files in your libs directory?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I have two : `android/app/libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar` and `android/app/libs/isoparser-1.0.6.jar`

Comment: Okay, so no known issues there.. Well, if you look at that sign-in library, it already compiles the play services library, so not sure why you'd exclude it and import it yourself. https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/android/build.gradle#L25

Comment: @cricket_007 No idea. Thier setup guide https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/android-guide.md Ask us to do it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653992/found-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-places9-2-1-but-version-9-0-2-is-ne

Comment: Based on the message `auth:9.2.1, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.` That to me says your Google Services Plugin is outdated and the first error was closer to the solution than the version downgrade

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks but I was unable to update it to a newer version. In the top of the logs (In my gist), it says it can't find that module and going to use the default 9.0.0. Any idea how to update it safely?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for pointing out the exclude! I removed it and also the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0` and now the app works. Any idea how to upgrade the play-services?

Comment: Using the SDK manager, at the bottom there is "Google Repository" and "Google play services"

Comment: @cricket_007 Have already installed and updated them. `Google Repository 41`, `Google Play Services 38`

Comment: Alright, well, not sure why it would think the versions are bad, then